# Implementing chat application only after login and GUI customization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, chat

I am making an application that performs the chat functionality between members that are within the application so that the two people can chat if they are logged in. This chat functionality should resemble gmail chat service in terms of Graphical User Interface and also with functionality.  I am using chatter gem. Using it, I am able to create GUI and functionality like that.

But now I have two problems:

1. It works after login but I can also chat before login too. I don't know how to restrict it to only work after login.
2. How can I customize the GUI to be more friendly. I mean is there any alternative to change GUI according to what's suits good.

Also tell me if there is better way to implement chat functionality that is similar to gmail chat.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters this might help you?

Answer (score 0):

1.) Happy to look at some code and help you out with it. In general, you're going to need to put in some custom logic into the controller in charge of the chat functionality that restricts usage to post-login. I'm not too familiar with 'chatter', but I know it is linked to the devise gem, so take a look at that relationship in specific. Most likely, you'll need a `before_filter` in the controller that ensures that a user is authenticated.

2.) Take a look at the following links for more detail on real-time chat between users:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/104611/real-time-chat-in-ruby-on-rails

[Implementing chat in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369263/implementing-chat-in-rails)

[Ruby on Rails 3 - Public live chat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156729/ruby-on-rails-3-public-live-chat)